# Decoding snydrome decoding

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory

Say the parity matrix is:
[[-1. -1.  0.]
[ 0. -2. -2.]
[-1.  0. -2.]
[ 1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  1.]]

The codewords:
c = [[1, 0, 2, 0,  1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1], [1,1,1,2,0,1]]

And the coding table: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
(0.0, 0.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2)
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
(0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
(0.0, 1.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2)
(0.0, 2.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0)
(0.0, 2.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1)
(0.0, 2.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
(1.0, 0.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
(1.0, 0.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2)
(1.0, 1.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(1.0, 1.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2)
(1.0, 2.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
(1.0, 2.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1)
(1.0, 2.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2)
(2.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)
(2.0, 0.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1)
(2.0, 0.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2)
(2.0, 1.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0)
(2.0, 1.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1)
(2.0, 1.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2)
(2.0, 2.0, 0.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0)
(2.0, 2.0, 1.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1)
(2.0, 2.0, 2.0) (0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2)

with m = 3, how would you go about decoding c? The answer is [[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1]]. I have already looked up plenty of sites but I can't seem to find the solution/algorithm to solving this.

It's a mystery to me how the vectors went from size = 6 to size = 3. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is not a homework/exam answering site. furthermore you don't even specify the code alphabet nor format your question properly.

Comment: @kodlu Where did I ask for the answer exactly? I'm simply asking for the algorithm that should be used, but go off